# How to access to specific div?

Tags: jquery

I want get all the options inside that structure:

```
<div id='navbar-left'>
   <div class='custom-dropdown' />
   <div class='custom-dropdown'>
       <select class='nav-select hidden'> 
           <option />
           <option/>
       </select>
   </div>
```

I tried: `var countries = $('#navbar-left > div[2] > select');`

but I get no content, what I did wrong?

Comment: `$('#navbar-left option')` would do it

Comment: Change `div[2]` to `div:eq(2)`

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you really want from those options... The value or the HTML?

For the value:

```js
$('#navbar-left option').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='navbar-left'>
 <div class='custom-dropdown' />
 <div class='custom-dropdown'>
   <select class='nav-select hidden'> 
     <option value="1">One</option>
     <option value="2">Two</option>
   </select>
 </div>
 </div>
```

For the HTML:

```js
$('#navbar-left option').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='navbar-left'>
 <div class='custom-dropdown' />
 <div class='custom-dropdown'>
   <select class='nav-select hidden'> 
     <option value="1">One</option>
     <option value="2">Two</option>
   </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

**Now if you want it in a variable**... I guess it should be an array:

```js
var countries = [];

$('#navbar-left option').each(function() {
    countries.push($(this).val());
});

console.log(countries);  // An array of all the values
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='navbar-left'>
 <div class='custom-dropdown' />
 <div class='custom-dropdown'>
   <select class='nav-select hidden'> 
     <option value="US">United States of America</option>
     <option value="CA">Canada</option>
   </select>
 </div>
</div>
```